# Find missing numbers in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this column in T-SQL:

```
 1
 2
 3
 7
 10
```

have SQl a function for detect the missing numbers in the sequence 4,5,6 and 8,9 
  I have try 
            something like 
            if ( a-b >1 )  then we have a missing number

with coalesce but i dont understand .
Thanks by any orientation

Comment: It would help if you posted the function...

Comment: If you have such a fucntion, what is your question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff "have SQL a function..." probably means "Has SQL a function...?" although of course this is only an educated guess

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
DELCARE @a
SET @a = SELECT MIN(number) FROM table
WHILE (SELECT MAX(number) FROM table ) > @a
BEGIN
IF @a NOT IN ( SELECT number FROM table )
PRINT @a
SET @a=@a+1
END
```

Comment: #winces# While this probably works, SQL is designed best to work in 'sets'; basically, without iterators/loops.  Certain applications of loops _may_ result in better performance, but it's almost always going to be beaten by the set-based approach.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse OK set is typically faster than cursor.  Please present a set based solution to the stated question.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will identify where each sequence starts and the number that are missing:

```
select t.col + 1 as MissingStart, (nextval - col - 1) as MissingSequenceLength
from (select t.col,
             (select min(t.col) from t t2 where t2.col > t.col) as nextval
      from t
     ) t
where nextval - col > 1
```

This is using a correlated subquery to get the next value in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but here is a query that uses recursive table expressions to get the missing values between the minimum and maximum values in a table:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    --This is called once to get the minimum and maximum values
    SELECT nMin = MIN(t.ID), MAX(t.ID) as 'nMax' 
    FROM Test t
    UNION ALL
    --This is called multiple times until the condition is met
    SELECT nMin + 1, nMax 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE nMin < nMax
)

--Retrieves all the missing values in the table.
SELECT c.nMin
FROM CTE c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM Test
    WHERE c.nMin = ID
)
```

This was tested with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    ID int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Test
    Values(1)

INSERT INTO Test
    Values(2)

INSERT INTO Test
    Values(3)

INSERT INTO Test
    Values(7)

INSERT INTO Test
    Values(10)
```